# vscode move cursor to next highlighted word

Tags: visual-studio-code

using an extension like es6 snippets, we get a block of code when we need to replace the highlighted words :

[Example of block of code with highlighted words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDuNJ.png)

My question is what is the shortcut to move to the next highlighted word ( item in the picture).

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the cursor to the next *tabstop* location of the *code snippet* with the **Tab key**.